# Why the x and y - axis values do not appear by default when making a bar chart using swift charts framework in swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, charts

when using charts framework to make a Bar Chart after creating my fake data and creating the chart in the contentView no x or y axis contents appeared I was following a tutorial and they appeared with him any one can help

[image]

```
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct Items : Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    let type : String
    let value : Double
}
struct ContentView: View {
    let items : [Items] = [
        Items(type: "Medical", value: 10000),
        Items(type: "Engeneering", value: 5000),
        Items(type: "singing", value: 15000),
        Items(type: "pilot", value: 1000),
        Items(type: "athlete", value: 18000),
        
    ]
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView{
            ScrollView{
                Chart(items){item in
                    BarMark( x: .value("Job", item.type),
                             y: .value("salary", item.value)
                    )
                    .foregroundStyle(.brown)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    
                    
                }
               
                .frame(height: 200)
                .padding()
                
                
                
            
            }
            .navigationTitle("Charts")
            
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Your code works well for me in my tests, on MacOS 14, Xcode 15, tested on real ios 17 devices (not Previews), and macCatalyst.
 It could be different on older systems. I can see both axis. Note, `NavigationView`
 is deprecated, you should use `NavigationStack` instead.

Comment: Also works well for me in my tests on iPhone 14 Pro simulator with iOS-16.